# Is application-development a useful tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

It seems a bit of a meta tag to me.

But I can also see some desire to keep it (I have used it myself!)

Answer (score 5):

I think so.  The reasoning is multi-faceted.

The people that follow it either know, or know people that know (I suspect there are about 10 people in that tag with the majority of the answers).

It's a simple way to consolidate programming related questions (we're not SO, we shouldn't have a python, c++, c, etc set of tags).

It's a great way for a tag search to zero in on new questions that should be closed as OT.

Comment: I would say the python tag (currently with 499 questions) is perfectly on topic (depending on whether the question is Ubuntu-y)

Comment: I'm a python fan too, it's just context.  Most questions tagged as 'python' are more sysadmin scripts than programming questions imo *as they should be*

Answer (score 0):

It might be called [application-development](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/application-development), but what it really is is a tag for ubuntu-the-platform.

It tends to cover the intersection of packaging, programming, and process (like quickly, etc.) It's been tremendously active during the app contest, I think it's one of our best tags, *snif*.